# Magento Image processing extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Is there any extension which is specifically goes for fill image color like module. I have 1000's of images which all same size but have white space around all image, instead of using photoshop can i use PHP to process that image to have different(brown color - sine it is background) instead of white. If there is any extension please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have same background for all images,you can override the magento class that applies background color.

File is `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php`

Find the code that looks like this `protected $_backgroundColor  = array(255, 255, 255);` and specify the RGB value of the colour that you want.

Comment: ?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
->constrainOnly(TRUE)
->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
->keepFrame(FALSE)
->resize(600,null)
?>
 By using this i have resolved my problem half way and now i wil do background color update, thanks blackcaps.

Comment: @blackcaps i'd like to know about upload image product without reduce the quality. how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Check out ImageMagick.  I haven't used it for exactly what you are trying to do, but I have used it for other kinds of batch image processing.  It can be ran from the commandline, but also has APIs for several programming languages.

For what you are trying to do, I'd take a look at the -fill, -floodfill, and -fuzz options.
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fill

Comment: can you please tell me how to integrate imagmagick in magento site

Answer (score 2):

I got solution for my problem by the following method.

```
<?php 

echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
->constrainOnly(TRUE)
->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
->keepFrame(FALSE)
->resize(600,null)

?>
```

I got it from here.

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-resize-image/

Answer (score 1):

You should consider getting rid of that white space unless you have other reason for it, e.g. to have product images to scale.

This is best achieved with Photoshop if you have got it, if the white is absolutely, definitely white then you can take the top-left pixel and crop from that.

Another option you may wish to consider is using png images, again this depends on your images and skill in Photoshop, however, you can use transparency in png and have no border on your images.

Also, in photoshop or imagemagick you may want to consider making your own thumbnail images, separate to the product page image. This will enable you to apply filters such as sharpen to get product page images that are a cut above your competitors.

As noted by @jmspldnl you can use imagemagick on the command line as well as php extension. On the command line you can work out the process and string together lots of steps, when happy with your options, rather than re-work it in php code you can use 'passthru()' and run what you worked out from the command line.

For going forward you can put a cron job that monitors your images folder and processes and images that have been changed/added in the last day. This will make it easier  to just upload images and have your system do the work.

Comment: Yes Mathew , Most of the images were irregular in height and width, so magento did re-size in ratio based resizing. So forced it to re-size what i want and now seems to be OK, but definitely in future i would ask for correct image rather doing it in code. Thanks